# Load partial view in main view by passing return main view in controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a main view where I am using html. Beginform{}. Initially page will have just two text box and search button. Once I input text and click on search data loads in same view along with partial view and some other controls from main view. So in controller method I am passing return view.. That is main view. This is working properly but I need to load same page through other page on click.. So I am. Using ajax post and fetching data and trying to load in partial view in main view, but this is not reflecting.. Same main view with just text box and button is displayed.. . Any idea how to solve??
Public index(){ return(main view)
}

Public search(){
Fetch data and return(main view, model)

In ajax also I am. Calling search method

Controller

```
   [HttpPost] 
    public IActionResult SearchApplicant(string employeeID, string AppId, PERMQuestionnaireViewModel model1) 
    { 
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    { 
        PERMQuestionnaireViewModel model = _permService.GetapplicantData(employeeID, AppId); 
        return View("../Tig/GreenCardIndex", model); 
    } 
    else 
       return Unauthorized(); 
    }
```

Ajax call

```
 $('#btnProcessGc').on('click', function () 
    { 
    var appId = $("input[name='ApplicationID']:checked").val(); post("/TigPerm/GreenCardProcessing", { applicationID: appId }) 
    $.ajax({ 
    //url: '@(Url.Action("EditJobOrder", "Tig"))', 
    url: "/TigPerm/SearchApplicant", type: "Post", dataType: "html", 
    data: { "EmployeeID": "", "AppId": appId }, 
    success: function (data) { $('#panel').html(data); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your controller, ajax and view code to understand question.

Comment: Controller method:[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SearchApplicant(string employeeID, string AppId, PERMQuestionnaireViewModel model1)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                PERMQuestionnaireViewModel model = _permService.GetapplicantData(employeeID, AppId);

                
                return View("../Tig/GreenCardIndex", model);

            }
            else
                return Unauthorized();

        }

Comment: in view i am using html.beginform(post method)

Comment: $('#btnProcessGc').on('click', function () {
    var appId = $("input[name='ApplicationID']:checked").val();
    post("/TigPerm/GreenCardProcessing", { applicationID: appId })
    $.ajax({
        //url: '@(Url.Action("EditJobOrder", "Tig"))',
        url: "/TigPerm/SearchApplicant",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { "EmployeeID": "", "AppId": appId },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#panel').html(data);  },  i am Calling partial view after i get value from post method as   @await Html.PartialAsync("_ApplicantGCSummaryGrid", Model)

Comment: Can you show GreenCardProcessing method code?